# Is Baire's theorem stronger than needed for functional analysis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, teaching

Many classic theorems in functional analysis involve using Baire's theorem to prove facts about topology that relate to maps between Banach spaces (or, more generally, F-spaces). The application always works as follows:

1. Construct a countable family of closed sets whose union is a Banach space (or an F-spaces).
2. Baire's theorem states that if all of these sets have empty interiors, then because their complements are all open and dense, the intersection of all the complements must be dense. But from (1) we know the intersection of all complements must be empty. Therefore at least one of the sets has nonempty interior.
3. Pick a member of the family with nonempty interior, pick a ball within that interior, and use it to prove a theorem.

My question is: doesn't Baire's theorem seem a little strong for these purposes? All you need to prove is that a certain set is nonempty (the intersection of all the complements), but instead you end up showing that it is **dense**.

So I'm curious: is the intersection of open dense subsets being nonempty equivalent to that intersection being dense? And if not, is there a pedagogically simpler route to proving (2) for introductory students that doesn't require them to understand Baire's theorem?

Comment: If it holds *for all open subspaces* of a given space that the intersection of a countable family of open dense sets is nonempty, then it also holds that the intersection of a countable family of open dense sets is dense. Thus, when proving the usual versions of Baire's theorem (for locally compact Hausdorff spaces, or for open subspaces of completely metrizable spaces), proving nonemptiness is equivalent to proving density.

Comment: Even for a single space, Baire's theorem is equivalent to the claim that the intersection is *somewhere* dense, i.e. dense on some open set, because if it weren't, you could intersect with the complement of its closure to get an empty set.

Comment: The "non-empty" artificially weaker version of Baire's theorem would also require to (artificially) assume that the ambient space is nonempty (on the empty set, the intersection of the sequence $(U_n)$ of dense open subsets $U_n=\emptyset$ is empty...)

Comment: Also Emil Jeřábek's suggestion and mine are, in general, the two most common strategies for proving the equivalence of results proving the existence of one example of something and results proving the existence of many examples - either apply the "exists one" theorem on many different subsets to get many examples, or, if there are few examples, add extra conditions to rule them out and derive a contradiction.

Comment: @WillSawin I think I understand how your argument says that my "weak version" of Baire's theorem (intersection of countably many open dense sets is nonempty) implies that the intersection of countably many open dense subsets must be somewhere dense. But how does this imply it is everywhere dense?

Comment: Baire's theorem is a fact in general topology. The vector space structure plays no role.

Comment: @user_35 I never said it did. In fact I italicized the word "somewhere" to emphasize the distinction!